# Git: Swap between repos

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository

I have to remote repos in one folder, after writing git remote -v I obtain:

```
A   https://github.com/A/repo.git (fetch)
A   https://github.com/A/repo.git (push)
B   https://github.com/B/repo.git (fetch)
B   https://github.com/B/repo.git (push)
```

Currently I'm on branch master of A, but I would like to swap to master branch of B, how can I do this? Command git checkout allows me only to change branches of A, but it does not work if I want to connect with B.

Comment: what do you mean? git checkout can let you checkout whatever branch from whatever repo (as long as the branch has been "fetched" from the remote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you use `git clone https://github.com/A/repo.git` in your local folder, and then changes the remote `origin` to `A` and add remote `B` in your local folder. So all the local branches belongs to repo A.

If you want you local branch based on `B/master`, you can use `git checkout -b master1 B/master`, and then replace the `master` if you want.

If you just want to work on repo B, you can use `git clone https://github.com/B/repo.git` and add repo `A` as remote.

Answer (score 1):

you can checkout it by specifying the name of your remote before the branch name.

`git checkout B/master`

See you.